# Why is mutate choking on a function variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

This works fine:

```
top_two <- c("Alderaan", "Chandrila")

starwars %>%
  drop_na(homeworld) %>%
  filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
  mutate(homeworld = ifelse(homeworld %in% top_two,
                            paste(top_two, collapse = " or "),
                            homeworld)) %>%
  count(homeworld) %>%
  mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
```

But when I try to transform that into a function, it chokes on "mutate"

```
census <- function(my_var, top_two){

starwars %>%
    drop_na({{my_var}}) %>%
    filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
    mutate({{my_var}} = ifelse({{my_var}} %in% top_two,
                              paste(top_two,collapse = " or "),
                              {{my_var}})) %>%
    count({{my_var}}) %>%
    mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
}
top_two <- c("Alderaan", "Chandrila")

census(homeworld, top_two)
```

The error is

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
> "  filter(gender == "feminine") %>%   mutate({{my_var}} ="

If I indicate `my_var` literally it works fine:

```
census <- function(my_var, top_two){
  starwars %>%
      filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
      drop_na({{my_var}}) %>%
      mutate(homeworld = ifelse({{my_var}} %in% top_two,
                                paste(top_two, collapse = " or "),
                                {{my_var}})) %>%
      count({{my_var}}) %>%
      mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new column using non-standard evaluation you have to use `:=`. Also it is better to pass dataframe as an argument to the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

census <- function(data, my_var, top_two){
  
  data %>%
    drop_na({{my_var}}) %>%
    filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
    mutate({{my_var}} := ifelse({{my_var}} %in% top_two,
                               paste(top_two,collapse = " or "),
                               {{my_var}})) %>%
    count({{my_var}}) %>%
    mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
}

top_two <- c("Alderaan", "Chandrila")
census(starwars, homeworld, top_two)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  homeworld                 n percent
#  <chr>                 <int> <chr>  
#1 Alderaan or Chandrila     2 13%    
#2 Coruscant                 2 13%    
#3 Kamino                    1 7%     
#4 Mirial                    2 13%    
#5 Naboo                     3 20%    
#6 Ryloth                    1 7%     
#7 Shili                     1 7%     
#8 Tatooine                  2 13%    
#9 Zolan                     1 7%
```

Comment: It's adding a new row, not a new column. But this seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by new row? It gives the same output as the code without function at the top of your post. Is that not expected? Does it work differently for you?

Comment: `Alderaan or Chandrila     2 13%`  is a row not a column.

Comment: @Amanda How can that be a column? What is your expected output? Isn't it same as `starwars %>% drop_na(homeworld) %>% filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
  mutate(homeworld = ifelse(homeworld %in% top_two, paste(top_two, collapse = " or "),  homeworld)) %>% count(homeworld) %>% mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))` ?

Comment: I'm confused but I think we're saying the same thing. It's adding a new row.